# Is this some kind of special usage of the verb "make"?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, parsing

Is this some kind of special usage of the verb "make"?

> Make him do your homework.

also this one:

> The teacher makes the things hardly understandable.

Is there any grammatical logic in these usages of the verb?

Answer (score 1):

It's just the meaning of *make*.

*X makes Y" means "X do/does something such that the result is X or X is created or completed."

*X make(s) Y Z" similarly means "X do/does something such that the result is Y has created or completed Z."

Comment: To add on to this, the first phase (Make him do...), make carries a meaning similar to "Force". It generally implies that the individual doesn't want to do a thing voluntarily, but they are being pressured or otherwise given no choice in the matter.

Answer (score 1):

> **Make** him do your homework

implies the following:

> **Force** him do your homework (if he does not want to do it willingly)

---

> The teacher **makes** the things hardly understandable

implies:

> The teacher **has a way of doing / explaining** the things hardly understandable

Comment: makes things hard to understand. barely understandable.